# inputrc setting is lost after pressing enter

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gdb, gnuplot

I have been bothered by this problem for a while, which affects gdb, bash, gnuplot...etc, almost anything that uses readline. (Surprisingly, csh works without any problem).

The problem is that the backspace would delete a whole word instead of a character. I modified the ~/.inputrc file and after C-x/C-r, it correctly deletes one character. However, after enter is pressed (either to run a command or just starting a new line), the setting in inputrc seems lost again and C-x/C-r is needed again to correct the behavior. I am wondering if someone knows what happened here.

Thank you...

Comment: What did you change in your `.inputrc`? Did you change something just before this started? What does your `.inputrc` file look like?

Comment: It essentially has just one line:  "^?": backward-delete-char. This line makes the backspace delete one character...The initial problem is that backspace delete the whole word, so I made this change. But it seems the environment constantly forgetting what's in the inputrc. Thank you.

Comment: When backspace is misbehaving what does `bind -V` output? (Specifically for backspace/`^?`?) If you run `set -x` then hit `C-xC-r` and then hit enter do you see anything running `bind` or anything else that might be changing your readline bindings?

Comment: bind -V output seems normal, which show a list of flag settings. The outputs both before C-xC-r and after C-xC-r are exactly the same. After set -x, I did not see anything running with enter either.

Comment: Bleh, `bind -v` isn't what I meant at all. What do `bind -q backward-kill-word` and `bind -q backward-delete-char` output when it is working and when it isn't working?

Comment: The only difference is that "\C-?" appears for `bind -q backward-delete-char` when it is working. But after an 'enter', this was lost.

Comment: Here is the full output: `backward-kill-word can be invoked via "\e\C-h", "\e\C-?".
 bash-3.2$ bind -q backward-delete-char
 backward-delete-char can be invoked via "\C-h".
 bash-3.2$ bind -q backward-delete-char
 backward-delete-char can be invoked via "\C-h", "\C-?".
 bash-3.2$ bind -q backward-kill-word
 backward-kill-word can be invoked via "\e\C-h", "\e\C-?".
`

Comment: Does this happen in the shell you get if you run `bash --norc --noprofile`? I can't think of what might be doing this other than something running before/after every command (like `PROMPT_COMMAND` or `PS1` something) unless there's an odd readline setting at play here.

Comment: Everything is still the same even for running bash with those options. I tried to echo the values for the two variables. `PROMPT_COMMAND` gives nothing and `PS1` gives `\s-\v\$`. Could this be the problem?

Comment: No, that's the default value and should be perfectly fine. That (and the fact that other applications are affected too really) says the problem isn't a shell config issue. Which means it must be a readline issue or something. Is enter/`\C-m` bound to something funny if you check `bind -p`'s output? If you hit `\C-j` instead of enter to submit a command does the problem still happen?

Comment: `bind -p` shows \c-m and \c-j are both bond to "accept-line". Using \C-j instead of enter does not change anything. The problem is still here.